# How to write a elastic search query to get the list of 50 questions with the date and the count

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I need to use 2 below MUST conditions while writing the elastic search query

MUST - ("source.keyword": "SONAX1")

MUST - ("answer.keyword": "UNHANDLED")

Required fields ( Questions & timestamp & aggregation count) & SIZE = 50 records needed

My timestamp is in epoch format and while displaying the records need to show in the date format.

Below is the query Tried

{

"query":{ "bool": { "must": { "term": { "answer.keyword": "UNHANDLED" } }, "must": { "term": { "source.keyword": "sonax" } } } }, "aggs": { "MyBuckets": { "terms": { "field": "question.keyword",”timestamp”, "sort":{ "_timestamp": "desc" "_source": { "includes": [ "source":"question.keyword",”timestamp”,

},
"size": "50"
} } } }

Below is the errors:

1. Duplicate Key must syntax error

[image]

Please check this: some synatx is missing

[image]

Comment: and what goes wrong when you run that query?

Comment: Duplicate Key must syntax error. Please check the above screenshot. I think We need to modifiy the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

incorrect json, it will duplicate names because of the must.
Please try:

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "term":{
                  "answer.keyword":"UNHANDLED"
               }
            },
            {
               "term":{
                  "source.keyword":"sonax"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. First criteria is fine. But the 2nd criteria query aggregations not working properly. Can you check the above mentioned. screenshot please. Actually I want to show the output List of 50 questions & Date & Count.

Comment: the agg part is a no sense, without mapping and some example it s impossible to fix it. Please dont send screen shot, at least join valid json (use online formater).

"field":"question.keyword", "”timestamp” => why you add timestamp here?
If you want to group by (= agg) sorting using timestamp you have to use bucket_sort:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-sort-aggregation.html

Comment: I would need your help to add the timestamp also inside this query. Could you please help me? where to add the timestamp
{
  "size":0,
    "query":{
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term":{
        
        "answer.keyword": "UNHANDLED"
          }
        },
      
      {
        "term":{
      "source.keyword": "Sonexo" 
        }
            }
         ]
  
   }
},

"aggs": {
  "MyBuckets": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "question.keyword",
      "order":{
        "_count": "desc"
      },
      "size": "10"

}
}
}
}

Comment: Sorry to trouble you so much. I am almost achieved it. Once last help from you. Finding difficulties to add the field "timestamp" also inside the query.

Comment: Sorry but i dont understand what s you try to do with this timestamp field. Share exemple please, it is for a sort ? a range query ? aggregate by timestamp window ?

Comment: Sorry please ignore my previous post. I solved my issue. Thanks for your help